# Code duplication in generator functions in Python

Tags: python, generator

One of the advantage of procedural programming is the ability to extract any piece of code into a function, which could be reused in many places, reducing code duplication. However, the `yield` statement in Python seems to reduce this ability, because when `yield` statement is extracted into another function, the original generator function becomes a normal one, and thus cannot be used as a generator anymore.

Consider this example:

```
def foo():
  do_something()
  bar = get_some_value()
  yield bar
  save(bar)
  do_something_else()
  # more code in between
  bar = get_some_value()
  yield bar
  save(bar)
  # finishing up
```

Note that the code around `yield` statements is always the same, but we can't extract it to a function.

Is this a known deficiency of Python or is there a workaround to reuse the code around `yield` statements?

Comment: Please provide some examples demonstrating your problem. Right now it is rather unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Are you referring to [Coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.3 or later:

```
def helper():
    bar = get_some_value()
    yield bar
    save(bar)

def foo():
  do_something()
  yield from helper()
  do_something_else()
  # more code in between
  yield from helper()
  # finishing up
```

In earlier Pythons (including Python 2):

```
def helper():
    bar = get_some_value()
    yield bar
    save(bar)

def foo():
  do_something()
  for x in helper(): yield x
  do_something_else()
  # more code in between
  for x in helper(): yield x
  # finishing up
```